# career as a salesforce developer

Tags: dev401

i just have completed my engineering course in Information Technology from RTMNU this year and i am a fresher and a new comer in the IT market. In final year, my project was based on salesforce.com and it was ofcoarse a live project.

I just want to know the prospects and scope of doing salesforce DEV-401 certification for me as a fresher, because after a survey, i found that most of the job opportunities as salesforce developer are for some experience holders.

Its my humble request to the experts to help me decide, whether to go for DEV-401 certification yet or not!!

Comment: Welcome to the forum! This question is a bit off topic (see http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/faq) as it is more for discussion than having a definitive answer. My experience is that many employers require both experience (2 years with Salesforce) and certification (401) however there are certainly others who do not.

Comment: I think requirements are quite different per region. Where there is a high demand I believe having a certification is much less an issue, afterall .. you can quickly reach it while working and gaining some extra experience.

Comment: I think this question should stay open, even though it's more of a discussion question. It's a common question among developers across ability levels. It'll continually come up, and the experts should weigh in, because a) this question will continuie to arise and b) this community is one of few out there who can best answer the question.....

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend you to do 401 if you are planning to pursue career as sfdc developer. The IT market has lot of opportunities  for salesforce developers as freshers due to huge demand for salesforce.Getting a certificate will boost your confidence and increase your knowledge and may help you to answer interview questions.A certificate will give an edge over other candidates.